# Homogeneous Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes

If $\{X_n\}$ is a homogeneous Markov chain, is it true that ${X_{n^2}}$ ($n$ is of the power $2$ not $X_n$) is also a homogeneous Markov chain? And why?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I know that its not true, but I dont know the counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example. Consider the random walk on $\mathbb Z$ that stays at its position, goes to right or left with probability $1/3$ each. We consider the a particular transition probability
\begin{align}
p_n(0,2):=\mathbb P(X_{n^2}=2 \mid X_{(n-1)^2}=0 )
\end{align} 
which, if $X_n$ is a homoegeneous Markov chain, should not depend on $n$. But guess what? It depends on $n$, we have
\begin{align}
p_1(0,2)=\mathbb P(X_1=2\mid X_0=0)=0
\end{align}
while 
\begin{align}
p_2(0,2)=\mathbb P(X_4=2\mid X_1=0)>0
\end{align}
Now it remains to think about why we have $p_2(0,2)>0$... Do you see why?

Comment: Alright. Thank you